# c++ Error compiler prototype & expect constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, compilation, prototype

I am having an issue with compiling my account.h and account.cpp files.
When compiling it is giving an error of prototype for account::account and saying it does not match any class of 'account' I am not sure what I am missing is it due to me calling it account::account. Or do I need to defined account in the header file. If I do how do I do so and how would it carry num and abal?
**Here is the exact error**

```
account.cpp:14:1: error: prototype for ‘account::account(int, float)’ does not match any in class ‘account’
 account::account(int num, float abal){
 ^
In file included from account.cpp:12:0:
account.h:15:7: error: candidates are: account::account(const account&)
 class account
       ^
account.h:15:7: error:                 account::account()
account.cpp:20:17: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 account::deposit(amount){
```

**Here is the program file**

```
//account.cpp

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "account.h"

account::account(int num, float abal){
    acctnum = num;
    intbal = abal;
}
//----------------------------------------------------
//Depositing into account
account::deposit(amount){
    if (amount < 0)
    {
        std::cout << endl <<"The deposit you've enter is negative." 
        << amount << " on account " << acctnum << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        balance = amount;
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------
//Withdrawing from account
//If withdrawel exceeds balance provide error and leave balance
//Else subtract withdrawel from account and update balance
account::withdraw(amount){
    if (amount < balance){
        std::cout << "Debit amount exceeded account balance." 
        << amount << " on account "<< acctnum << " with balance "
        << balance << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else if(amount < 0){
        std::cout <<"The withdrawel you've enter is defined as negative." 
        << amount << " on account "<< acctnum << " with balance "
        << balance << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        balance -= amount;
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------
//Insert intial balance of account
//If no balance included then give error message and set account balance to 0
account::int_balance(float amount){
    if (amount >= 0) {
        balance = amount;
    }
    else {
        balance = 0;
        std::cout << "Error intial balance invalid" << endl;
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------
account::balance(){
    return bal;
}
```

**Header file**

```
//account.h

#ifndef account_h_
#define account_h_

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class account
{
public:
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //account number
    int account_num() const {
        return acctnum;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //constructs bank account with inital_balance
    double balance() const {
        return bal;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //deposit into account
    void deposit(float amount) {
        bal += amount;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //withdrawal from account
    void withdraw(float amount) {
        amount - bal;
    }
private:
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //account number
    int acctnum;
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //balance
    double bal;
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

This signature, that you're trying to define in the .cpp file

```
account::account(int num, float abal)
```

has not been declared in the class definition in the header file.

You have to declare the constructor, with something like

```
account(int num, float abal);
```

in the class definition in the header file.